# ng-model value is not updating when i select all drop-down elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, multi-select, angular2-form-validation

My issue is when using a **ngModel for validation**. It is not working in **edge** browser when select a value via SelectAll option.

> not working sample code, Here i did not use **[(value)]**:

```html
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselect-checkbox' #checkbox [dataSource]='countries' name='formRequired' [placeholder]='checkWaterMark' (change)='onMultiChange(projectInfoTypeId, projectInfoText)' [fields]='checkFields'
                [mode]='mode' [popupHeight]='popHeight' [showDropDownIcon]='true' showSelectAll='true' [(ngModel)]='ProjectTypeId' #projectInfoTypeId='ngModel' [filterBarPlaceholder]='filterPlaceholder' required ></ejs-multiselect>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="projectInfoTypeId.errors?.required" class="validationText">
                                country is required.
                            </div>
```

I have validate this issue and **suspect** that **the value changes** are **not reflect** to **ngModel**. i have **bind same property to both value and ngModel**. This issue is resolved.

> Working sample code, Here i used **[(value)]**:

```html
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselect-checkbox' #checkbox [dataSource]='countries' name='formRequired' [placeholder]='checkWaterMark' (change)='onMultiChange(projectInfoTypeId, projectInfoText)' [fields]='checkFields'
                [mode]='mode' [popupHeight]='popHeight' [showDropDownIcon]='true' showSelectAll='true' [(value)]='ProjectTypeId' [(ngModel)]='ProjectTypeId' #projectInfoTypeId='ngModel' [filterBarPlaceholder]='filterPlaceholder' required ></ejs-multiselect>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="projectInfoTypeId.errors?.required" class="validationText">
                                country is required.
                            </div>
```

**Please provide any idea. I want know, is this a behavior or not**

> workig sample link:
>   [sample 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75cxtd-1lpkaj?file=checkbox.html)
>
> not working sample link:
>   [sample 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75cxtd-37dzkx?file=checkbox.html)
>
> Error:

if select all, the following error occurs:

**ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'preventDefault' of undefined or null reference**